# SQL Server : how to return highest agregated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-order-by, sql-limit

Jow can I return two highest aggregated results?

For example, I have a result like this:

```
CustomerId   Total
---------------------
    5        1100.00
   n/a        100.00
    7         100.00
    6           0.00
```

and I need to return max 2 highest rows like this:

```
CustomerId    Total
-----------------------
    5         1100.00
    7          100.00
   n/a         100.00
```

I tried with `TOP 2`, but the problem is that I do not know how can I return more rows if there are rows with the same value.

Here is my query at the moment

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50), u.CustomerId), 'not found') CustomerId ,
    ISNULL(SUM(o.Total), 0.00) Total
FROM 
    Orders o 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    CustomerId u ON u.UserId = o.UserId
GROUP BY
    u.CustomerId 
ORDER BY 
    Total DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want `WITH TIES`?

```
SELECT TOP (2) WITH TIES
    ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50), u.CustomerId), 'not found') CustomerId ,
    ISNULL(SUM(o.Total), 0.00) Total
FROM Orders o 
FULL OUTER JOIN CustomerId u ON u.UserId = o.UserId
GROUP BY u.CustomerId 
ORDER BY total desc;
```

It is quite unclear why you actually need a `FULL JOIN`. Unless you have orphan orders, that should be a `LEFT JOIN` starting from the customers table and then going to the orders table. It is also unclear why you have a table named `CustomerId`, with a column that has the same name. Ideally you would name that table `Customers` instead, so:

```
SELECT TOP (2) WITH TIES
    c.CustomerId
    ISNULL(SUM(o.Total), 0.00) Total
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIn Orders o ON u.UserId = c.UserId
GROUP BY c.CustomerId 
ORDER BY total desc;
```

Comment: That worked thank you. 
I didn’t think it would be that easy.

Answer (score 0):

First, an outer join should not be necessary, unless your data model is really messed.

You can use `TOP 2 WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP (2) WITH TIES u.CustomerId, SUM(o.Total)
FROM Orders o JOIN
     CustomerId u 
     ON u.UserId = o.UserId
GROUP BY u.CustomerId 
Order by Total desc;
```